# Pandas - strange rounding with float64 data

Tags: pandas, floating-point

I have the following input data:

```
trade
411170
181604
1571696
2046663
528474
175173
15151
257710
72036
100111
67241
171985
111292
78622
```

I am running th efollwoing commands on iPython and expect that the sum of the % (pct) column is one as I am calculating it as a percentage of the total shares. Instead I seem to have a very very close approximation. I would expect the floating point of Panda to take care of this.

```
In [644]: a = pd.read_clipboard()

In [645]: a.dtypes
Out[645]:
trade    int64
dtype: object

In [646]: a['trade'] = a['trade'].astype(float)

In [647]: a.dtypes
Out[647]:
trade    float64
dtype: object

In [648]: a['pct'] = a['trade'] / a['trade'].sum()

In [649]: a['pct'].sum()
Out[649]: 0.99999999999999989
```

I also tried doing `.astype(np.float)` (np being numpy).

Comment: You can `.round()` the result if you want to limit the number of decimal places

Comment: The "solution": [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: When using Pandas the number format is not Python "float" but Numpy's float64. This format shouldn't have floating point arithmetic issues (ie you get the same results you would on Matlab or Excel). That's why I am surprised to see this happen here.